# Three js OBJ loader creation not working in typesecript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js, 3d-model

> import * as THREEObjLoader from 'three-obj-loader';

`const objLoader = new THREEObjLoader(THREE);`

`objLoader is undefined.`

Could someone let me know why the object instance is not created?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use the `three-obj-loader` package anymore. Instead you can import all examples JS files from the main repository (`three`). For `OBJLoader`, it looks like so:

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
```